# MacBook Pro makes a scratching noise?

Tags: macbook-pro

Whenever I pick up my computer and it's on, it makes this horrible scratching sound. Where is this sound coming from? Am i wrecking the computer when this happens? How can i prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this problem as well an posted [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/43195/13414) which is very similar yours.

Here's my solution:

On the whole logic board you'll find **tiny elastic sticks**. They can be pushed a little. These sticks hold the aluminum bottom off the logic board and cause the disturbing mechanic noises that your are talking about.

Do not take any chances and apply **insulating tape** on every place of the aluminum bottom that the sticks can contact. Apply the tape **again** as it easily wears out.

Now, the Macbook Pro does not make any of the previous noises anymore. 
 It feels like a solid aluminum brick on my lap.

[image]

And a close up...

[image]

This is what the back cover looked like when I was done. Uh, it's ugly! I'm glad it's on the inside.

[image]

Comment: is it harmful for the computer?

Comment: @John I have done this three months ago. No problems occured since then.

Comment: No i mean is whatever is causing the sound bad for the computer?

Comment: @John I don't think so. You may see some wear marks on the bottom case, but that's normal. It's important that the electronics on the logic board do not touch the aluminium. Therefore the sticks are very important. After all, all Macs are hardware that is prone to mechanical 'bugs' and wear off.